# UITableViewHeaderView defaulting to hang over cell, not above

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, swift

I'm using UITableView's viewForHeaderInSection method, but I've decided the that the view would llook  nicer with a lowered opacity over the cell *by default*, where it starts like so:

[image: how it defaults]

I'd like it to default like this, as if the user had already scrolled down (note, I want this for all cells, not just the one currently at the top of the view).

[image: how i'd like it]

I could just add the view as a subview of the cell, except I want it to maintain the functionality where, if the cell is the top cell, the header view stays atop the screen. Maybe the proper way to do this is to not have a headerview, and if a cell is the top cell calculate where the view's origin.y on the cell - although this seems like a potentially expensive way to go about it, it may be the only / best.

Thanks.

PSI'm looking to do this in swift, but objective C would do. Thanks again

Comment: has anyone acheived this? I'm still struggling with it

Comment: what do you mean for all cells?  why would you want a translucent header for all cells?  what's wrong with returning a view with reduced opacity from the viewForHeaderInSection?  And what about the behavior as if user had already scrolled down you want to reproduce?  Is it me or your explanation?  lol

Comment: it sounds like you just want a plain UITableViewStyle header that's translucent?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity. The header defaults above the actual UITableViewCell, while I want it to share it's origin.y with the UITableViewCell's view's origin.y. Basically, the header is never "above" the cell, it just begins at the top of the cell instead of above it. Revisiting the images I posted may further understanding of my intention.

Comment: yeah... that's hella confusing, looks like you're doing something funky with the cell background view making it look continuous with the top cell... what happens when you scroll past the top cell of the section?  maybe you should upload more pictures to describe what you want.

Comment: That's what I want, not what I'm getting (unless I scroll downwards the size of the header). Basically, I want all my cells to be continuous (not separated by a header) but I still want the features of a header (namely, it not going out of the top of the tableView's frame until another header reaches it).

I don't know how further images will help. I want the cell to begin like the SECOND image I posted, while by default the header works like the first (in between cells). If that still doesn't make sense, I will post a few more examples - just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data = [[String]]()
    var headerOrigins = [CGPoint]()
    var floatingHeaders = [UIView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data = [["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eigth", "Nine", "Ten"], ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eigth", "Nine", "Ten"], ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eigth", "Nine", "Ten"]]

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        for i in 0..<data.count {
            headerOrigins += tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: i)).frame.origin

            let floatingHeader = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, headerOrigins[i].y, tableView.frame.size.width, 44))
            floatingHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            floatingHeader.alpha = 0.5

            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 10, 100, 30))
            label.text = "Header \(i)"
            floatingHeader.addSubview(label)

            tableView.addSubview(floatingHeader)

            floatingHeaders += floatingHeader
        }

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
        var tableTop = tableView.bounds.origin.y + tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.top

        if tableTop < 0 {
            floatingHeaders[0].frame.origin.y = 0
        } else {
            for i in 0..<data.count {
                if tableTop > headerOrigins[i].y {
                    floatingHeaders[i].frame.origin.y = tableTop
                } else if tableTop < headerOrigins[i].y {
                    floatingHeaders[i].frame.origin.y = headerOrigins[i].y
                }

            var j = i
            while j > 0 {
                if (CGRectGetMaxY(floatingHeaders[j-1].frame) > floatingHeaders[j].frame.origin.y) {
                    floatingHeaders[j-1].frame.origin.y = floatingHeaders[j].frame.origin.y - floatingHeaders[j].frame.size.height
                }
                j--
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile and following along with the code I don't think this would default the way I was hoping. Thank you for your attempt though